# How to close the ionic popup when mobile backbutton is pressed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using an ionic popup to add a new item but if I press the mobile back option the ionic popup is not closed as well as the popup option goes to the previous screen.I have tried using $ionicPopUp.close() but it didn't work.

```
function showPopup () {
  $scope.data = {};
  var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="data.expensetype">',
    title: 'Enter Expensetype',
    scope: $scope,
    buttons: [
     { text: 'Cancel' },
      {
        text: '<b>Save</b>',
        type: 'button-positive',
        onTap: function (e) {
          if (!$scope.data.expensetype) {
            //don't allow the user to close unless he enters producttype
            e.preventDefault();

          } else {
            addExpenseCategory();
            return $scope.data.expensetype;
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  });
  myPopup.then(function (res) {
    $log.log('Tapped!', res);
  });
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to close the ionic popup when the mobile back button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it by using registerBackButton Action

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function () {
    myPopup.close();
, 101);
```

Last line number represents event priority: Return to previous view = 100 Close side menu = 150 Dismiss modal = 200 Close action sheet = 300 Dismiss popup = 400 Dismiss loading overlay = 500.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `registerBackButtonAction` method as followed:

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
myPopup.close();
});
```